# Compute the Salt

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, security, hash

I want to compute salt for aspnet Membership.

```
  private static string CreateSalt(int size){
```

But what is the default size for the provider?(32 or 64?) I want to match it with sql server on my machine. Also could you please some algorithms?

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
     enablePasswordReset="true"
     connectionStringName="Membershiptest"
     minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
     applicationName="test"
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

I use SQL SERVER 2008 R2.I copy some salts here, so can we say their size are 24?

```
2Qjf2TYkDcp/wYKY1px7yg==

Ob+cmhSBCE4DFXKyF7ylAw==

65wVLQ1m+An6a9WGSv6SXA==

Tf0fdXoPw8FMr+KuhitvtQ==
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's base64 so it's actually 16 bytes not 24 bytes. The size is 16 or 128 depending on if you are wanting bytes or bits respectively.

Comment: So for this 24 bit salt I posted, what is the size?

Comment: @Love You posted 24 character strings that represents 16 byte(128 bit) salts.

Comment: [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) allows you to represent raw binary date with 64 ascii characters, and this adds about 33% overhead, if you use a base64 decoder `Convert.FomBase64String()` you'd get the actual byte array values and you'll find the length is 16.